# Authentication in header with REST API

Tags: rest, http, post, header

I am new to coding and trying to work with my first API in Javascript. I am having some trouble figuring out where to populate an API key and header. It is a POST for sending a small message to an IOT device. The reference is [here](https://www.hologram.io/references/http#/reference/sms/send-sms-to-device/send-cloud-message-to-device) and the header reference is [here](https://www.hologram.io/references/http#/introduction/authentication/header-example).

Here is what I have, but I have replaced my API key with the generic one.

```
request.open('POST', 'https://dashboard.hologram.io/api/1/devices/messages');


request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'deviceid': [storedDeviceID],
  'protocol': 'TCP',
  'port': 80,
  'data': 'Hello world!',
  'base64data': 'SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhCg=='
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573037/2422003

Comment: thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hologram provides an API Key which you need to encode in base64 format first then you can use it in your program.

So you can go to [base64encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) or any other conversion website ( you can encode it programmatically as well ) and there you have to enter -

```
apikey:YOUR_API_KEY
```

Then encode it into base64 format which will be something like

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOpQrstUVW==
```

Copy it, and use it in your program. Below is an example using Javascript Fetch API -

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOpQrstUVW==");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://dashboard.hologram.io/api/1/links/cellular", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```